How did they make copies of the 'international ohm'?
How did they create copies of the artifact based international standard resistance that was followed until the middle of the 20th century?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I suspect the following might be helpful: Wolff, F. A., Shoemaker, M. P., & Briggs, C. A. (1916). Construction of primary mercurial resistance standards (No. 256). US Department of Commerce, Bureau of Standards.

The history, which is followed in its development as published in Metrologia 46 pp 503-511, may be viewed here.  The succinct portion of the history is stated in the introductory paragraph to Section 2 regarding Thomas-type resistors.  The following is noted -

In the ‘international-reproducible’ system of metrology used
from 1893 through 1947 the 1 $\Omega$ value of resistance was defined by the mercury ohm, based on the resistance at 0$^{\small o}$C
of a column of mercury of specified physical characteristics.
Artefact standards in the form of wire-wound resistors at the
1 $\Omega$ resistance level were developed extensively in this period
for comparison with the mercury ohm and as working dc
resistance references. The alloy Manganin, with nominal
composition 84% Cu, 12% Mn and 4% Ni, was used for a
wide range of standard resistors of which many were developed
at the German Physikalisch-Technische Reichsanstalt.


Links can (and do) rot over time, so it is advisable to cite in full to make it easier to find a publication in the future: G. R. Jones, B. J. Pritchard, and R. E. Elmquist, "Characteristics of precision 1Ω standard resistors influencing transport behaviour and the uncertainty of key comparisons." Metrologia, Vol. 46, No. 5, Oct. 2009, pp. 503-511 (DOI 10.1088/0026-1394/46/5/015)
